# Periodic drops in SSD writing speed down to 20 MB/sec

Tags: linux, memory, ssd, performance, sata

Before yesterday I had extremely slow writing speeds on my SSD.
My main SSD has capacity of 1.7 TB.
I have another SSD but with smaller capacity of 960 GB.
I decided to test the writing speed of both SSD from a live linux os.
I tested the writing speed using this command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
```

I also tried these commands to get certain results:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1M count=1024 conv=fdatasync,notrunc
```

After tests I found that the main SSD writing speed was about 10 MB/sec. It's far from 400+ MB/sec expected. The writing speed of the second SSD was normal about 450 MB/sec.
Also I tested the reading speeds of both drives and they both were normal about 550 MB/sec.
The reading speed was tested using this command:

```
hdparm -t /dev/sdX
```

That meant the OS settings is not the problem as the problem persists on a live os as well.

So, I found somewhere that the problem might be with that there was not enough free space on it or TRIM command is not activated. It sounded earnestly because I actually didn't have much space on the disk, only about 50 GB from initial 1.7 TB. So I decided to wipe the disk.
I used this manual to clear memory cells on my SSD: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive/Memory_cell_clearing
Then I installed new OS and it helped. The speed became about 330 MB/sec. It still was not as expected 450 MB/sec, but much better than it was before.
So then I considered the problem as solved.

But today I faced this problem again, but less noticeable. The new problem is that the writing speed is still drops down to about 30 MB/sec, but not all the time, periodically.
I used a command that writes 1 GB to a disk without caching 10 times with 1 second delay between writes to demonstrate you a problem:

```
[user@host ~]$ for _ in {1..10}; do dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1M count=1024 conv=fdatasync,notrunc; sleep 1; done
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.58924 s, 415 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 27.303 s, 39.3 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 36.224 s, 29.6 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.59268 s, 414 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.57213 s, 417 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.57715 s, 417 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 45.9079 s, 23.4 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 14.8719 s, 72.2 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.58006 s, 416 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.58301 s, 416 MB/s
```

You can see that the writing speed drops down to 20 MB/sec sometimes. I tested this with no programs started at all (only XFCE desktop), so there was no other writes to the disk (I think). And it may be much worse when I usually use my computer with many programs started. I also monitored the system loading at the time of tests, and there was no CPU or memory loading, just to notice.

By the way, I used to use full disk encryption (LUKS), but I also tested the speed on an unencrypted partition (ext4) and the results was the same.

My partition scheme:

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda              8:0    0  1.7T  0 disk  
├─sda1           8:1    0  256M  0 part  
├─sda2           8:2    0   50G  0 part  
│ └─cryptroot  254:0    0   50G  0 crypt /
├─sda3           8:3    0  768G  0 part  
└─sda4           8:4    0    5G  0 part  /mnt
```

More than a half of the disk is free.

Do you know what could be a problem?

Comment: `for _ in {1..10}; do dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1M count=1024 conv=fdatasync,notrunc; sleep 1; rm test.img; done` - any difference with a `rm`in there?